# four square cipher encryption code

Tags: java, arrays, string

I need to take a string split it into 2 char increments, then find the corresponding locations of each string on a plain square containing the alphabet (-q) then, i need to take those locations given in the [0] and [1] values of an array and find a corresponding char in a cipher square. I have all the squares made but im having trouble getting the string manipulated. Here's what I have:

```
String[] splitMessage = message.split("(?<=\\G..)");
char []input = new char[message.length()];
char []encryptedInput = new char[message.length()];
int [] pos = new int[message.length()];
for (int n =0; n < message.length(); n++)
{
    String[] letter = splitMessage[n].split("");
    input = letter[n].toCharArray();
}   
for (int i =0; i < input.length;i+=2)
{
    pos = plain1.getPos(input[i]);

    for (int j =1; j < input.length; j+=2)
    {
        pos = plain2.getPos(input[j]);

        for (int k =0; k < input.length; k+=2)
        {
            char newLetter= cipher1.getChar(pos[k], pos[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this a Playfair cipher?

Comment: Not exactly, you still reference a 5x5 table but in a different way

Comment: What is the exact problem? What are you expecting to happen and what's happening instead? I can't see an answerable question here.